# grub: couldn't find a necessary member device of multi-device file system (Ubuntu, zfs on root)

Tags: 16.04, scripts, raid, grubrescue, zfs

I use a script to deploy "ZFS on root" on Ubuntu16.04. It configures multiple disks as raidz, raidz2, raidz3 or mirror. While this script has always worked in the past, it seems to be running into problems now.

When I reboot after configuring zfs I get the following error from grub:

```
 error: couldn't find a necessary member device of multi-device filesystem

Entering rescue mode...
```

Grub is installed on all disks and grub-probe tells me that the filesystem is "zfs".

I suspect it could be related to a grub update... Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the virtualbox disk controllers only allow 4 disks per controller (SATA, SCSI, ...). Dividing the amount of disks along these controllers, resolved this issue.